# replicate Arduino's serial monitor on Scilab consol

Tags: serial-port, tcl, serial-communication, scilab

If I use the Arduino IDE's Serial monitor I can read the pair of comma separated values as below:

> [image]

I want to first replicate this behavior in SciLab terminal. I used the [Serial Communication Toolbox](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/serial):

```
h = openserial(7, "9600,n,8,1") // open COM7
disp(readserial(h))
closeserial(h)
```

which returns either empty or

> , 169
>
> 228, 179
>
> 228,
>
> 228, 205
>
> 228, 209 228,

putting the `disp(readserial(h))` in a while loop also doesn't help. Not only there are too many empty lines, if I stop the while loop it does not close the port (something like try-catch should be used I think). I would appreciate if you could help me know how I could get the same behavior as Arduino's serial monitor?

**P.S.** Next I want to plot these two values in realtime. So maybe using the `csvTextScan` function to split the string into two integers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a couple of days struggling I figured this out. It turns out that SciLab doesn't have native serial communication functionality and the Toolbox developer has used `TCL_EvalStr` to run Tcl commands externally. I had to dig into the Tcl serial communication syntax (i.e. `read`, `open`, `gets`, `fconfigure` ... ), ask [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935990/read-the-latest-line-of-a-serial-port), get [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54941773/4999991) and then finally end up with a new function for the Toolbox which I have committed as [a pull request](https://github.com/sengupta/Scilab-Serial/pull/8/commits):

```
function buf = readserialline(h)
    tmpbuf = emptystr();
    while tmpbuf == emptystr()
        TCL_EvalStr("gets " + h + " ttybuf");
        tmpbuf = TCL_GetVar("ttybuf");
    end
    buf = tmpbuf;
endfunction
```

now one can get the above behavior by running:

```
h = openserial(7, "9600,n,8,1") // open COM7

for ii = 1:40
    disp(readserialline(h))
end

closeserial(h)
```

to read the serial port line by line and print it to the SciLab console. Now to parse the CSV data you may use:

```
 csvTextScan(part(readserialline(h), 1:$-1), ',')
```

> [image]

**P.S.1.** I have used a virtual Arduino board inside SimulIDE and used com0com to create virtual serial ports. More information [here on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/simulide/discussion/general/thread/a53c097f6a/#34c6/7d5f/a80d).

**P.S.2.** More discussion with Toolbox developer Aditya Sengupta [here on Twitter](https://twitter.com/fsfarimani/status/1101466971546284032).

**P.S.3.** More discussions here on [Tcl Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/s5wcIAXft1M)

**P.S.4.** A full demonstration plus instructions [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/electronics/comments/awkoka/creating_a_virtual_arduino_in_simulide_and_serial/)

**P.S.5.** For those who might end up here, I have decided to rewrite Aditya Sengupta's repository [here](https://foadsf.github.io/ssct/) with several improvements.