# Scilab 5.5.2 function as a block in xcos : Variable returned by scilab argument function is incorrect [

Tags: arduino, real-time, serial-communication, scilab, xcos

I have been trying to get the ultrasonic data from an arduino using serial communication toolbox in scilab to be brought in the xcos simulation. To do this I followed [Include a Scilab function/script as a block in xcos/scicos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764607/include-a-scilab-function-script-as-a-block-in-xcos-scicos/54816664#54816664) and created my own function. Is there a way to plot the serialread data in xcos scope? or i think my implementation is wrong in the scilab function. Iam Using Windows 10 64bit

SCILAB function

```
function y = serialREAD(a)
    h = openserial(7, "9600,n,8,1") // open COM7
    for ii = 1:a
        y = strtod(part(readserialline(h), [1,2,3])) * (a/a)
    end
    closeserial(h)

endfunction
```

endfunction

XCOS block diagram

> [image]

The ERROR [ This error has been solved converted the string to a double using the strtod ]

> [image]

The Data in CMscope but not in realtime only after the simulation my final integration time is 100.

> [image]

Comment: please study [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54960839/4999991) thoroughly. And please mention the operating system you are using.

Comment: Studying the post and other few things I have successfully plotted the data in xcos but the problem is it is not in real time only after the simulation. I have Edited my function and will add a screenshot of the results

Comment: would you share files? on github gists for example.

Comment: absolutely  here is the github link https://github.com/mentablack/XCOS-SerialREAD-Block.git

Comment: I'm working on this issue because it is also required for my own research. I am trying to implement MATLAB's serial functionality in for Scilab. the latest developments can be seen in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/44fe9b5e2bcb02b22392adf6d8f7a871). feel free to study it and leave comments over there if you have questions.

Comment: Ok thanks for the resources . I'll try first by using the FROMWORKSPACE BLOCK to get the data from the serialread line to xcos